# Why are the attributes in AbstractLinkedList transient?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

I'm reading the Apache Commons source code to become a better programmer. I noticed in `AbstractLinkedList`:

```
transient Node<E> header;

/** The size of the list */
transient int size;

/** Modification count for iterators */
transient int modCount;
```

Don't we need these to be serialized/deserialized?

Comment: I can't say definitively but most of the time we see this is because the transient data is only there to give better performance during usage.  It is rebuilt after deserializing, either during the deserialization process, or on first usage after deserialization.

Comment: Not necessarily - I did not look at the source code, but the `size` for instance could be restored from the number of elements which have been read during deserialization, the `modCount` is probably 0 and the `header` is identical to the first element read.

Comment: @GlennLane Got it, I was wondering if these 3 attributes could really affect performance

Answer (score 1):

If your class implements the `Serializable` interface, by default, all the non-transient attributes are written out as a custom binary stream when you serialize the object. *But*, if you want to have more control over the way your "serialized data" is written out, you typically mark the "implementation dependent" attributes as trasient and implement your own custom `readObject`/`writeObject` methods for that particular class.

To prove this, you'll find that the [same class has methods like](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/AbstractLinkedList.java#AbstractLinkedList.doWriteObject%28java.io.ObjectOutputStream%29) `doReadObject` and `doWriteObject` which are called by the overridden `readObject` and `writeObject` methods respectively.

Comment: 5 minutes into reading source code, and I'm already amazed. Thank you.